# How can include a dot character in enum type name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, enums, naming

I'm using javascript and have this enumeration:

```
filterType = { Campaign : 'Campaign', Class : 'Class', Date : 'Date', 
               DateGeq : 'DateGeq', DateLeq : 'DateLeq', 
               DateRange : 'DateRange', Status : 'Status' }
```

I'd like to name it as:

```
Filter.filterType = { Campaign : 'Campaign', Class : 'Class', Date : 'Date', 
                      DateGeq : 'DateGeq', DateLeq : 'DateLeq', 
                      DateRange : 'DateRange', Status : 'Status' }
```

The interpreter doesn't like dot character.

Can I add a dot character in enumeration names???

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably getting an error because you're trying to assign a value to the `filterType` member on a class called `Filter`, but `Filter` is undefined. It'll work if you defined `Filter` first.

```
var Filter = {};
```

To do it all in one line you could write:

```
var Filter = { filterType: { ... } };
```

Comment: Just to nitpick, there's no class in javascript. Filter is an Object.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have "Filter" is undefined.

```
var Filter ={};
Filter.filterType = {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing like this?

```
Filter={}

Filter.filterType = { Campaign : 'Campaign', Class : 'Class', Date : 'Date', 
                      DateGeq : 'DateGeq', DateLeq : 'DateLeq', 
                      DateRange : 'DateRange', Status : 'Status' }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no *enumerations* in JavaScript.  What you have shown here is an object, more specifically, an [object literal](http://www.zebrakick.com/blog/object-literals-vs-constructed-objects-in-javascript/) constructed using [JSON notation](http://json.org).

You're second example is attempting to create a `filterType` property (which is a redundant name, by the way) on an object named `Filter`.  If `Filter` doesn't exist, it will cause an error (consider it analogous to `null.filterType` which obviously doesn't make any sense).  You must first define `Filter`.

To define `Filter` and `Filter.filterType` in one expression, you can use the following notation:

```
var Filter = {
    filterType: {
        Campaign : 'Campaign', Class : 'Class', Date : 'Date', 
        DateGeq : 'DateGeq', DateLeq : 'DateLeq', 
        DateRange : 'DateRange', Status : 'Status'
    }
};
```